# How to access values from html form in mulesoft flow as to send them as email?

Tags: mule

I m using a html form to take some details from user like name , image. I want to use these details in mulesoft flow to send the details to a user via email. 
How can i achieve this?
Please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, what is the input format coming to your mule flow? is that HTML form or any other format of data? Please provide more dtails to understand your use case better.

Comment: If you are sending the data as ```multipart/form-data``` it will be available in the mule message as attachments. Once you tried something you should add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Parse Template transformer, you can load the contents of the HTML page in a Mule flow and use MEL in your HTML page and access payload, variables, etc.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/parse-template-reference

https://www.appnovation.com/blog/mule-esb-using-static-templates-produce-dynamic-content

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer: you can access the values from the form through

```
#[payload.get("value")]
```